# Is there a way of searching Firefox bookmarks by multiple tags without going into the bookmarks menu?

Tags: firefox, search, bookmarks, tags

For bookmarks I know we have two options:

- Option 1: Bookmarks Menu → drop-down bookmarks menu listing
- Option 2: Bookmarks Toolbar → one click access to bookmarks

Is there some add-on/extension for Firefox which lets you search your bookmarks by multiple tags from Firefox without going to the bookmarks menu?

I want to be able to type:

```
Tags: work,book
```

into something like the Google search bar in the top right hand corner. Kind of like how you can use searches in Evernote and Gmail.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This feature is built into the address bar.

All you need to do is type a <kbd>+</kbd>, a <kbd>Space</kbd>, and then each tag, separated by a <kbd>Space</kbd>. So, if you wanted to search for all items tagged with both "comedy" and "video", you would type `+ comedy video` directly into the address bar.

Source: [Awesome Bar - Find your bookmarks, history and tabs when you type in the address bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-find-your-bookmarks-history-and-tabs#w_changing-results-on-the-fly)

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a way to select them all.(Personal quest.)
I wrote an add-on for the original question, but with Webextensions it will be impossible to continue.https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bookmarks-x-tags/

Comment: It only shows first 10 items. What do I do if I want the 11th one?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor there is a way to increase the number of items shown in the address bar by making some changes in the about:config. Type about:config into the address bar,find browser.urlbar.maxRichResults then right click > Modify, and enter a higher number. You might need to restart Firefox to apply the change. Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1205508

Comment: **Outdated** for later Firefox ("Quantum"): see my answer on that.

Comment: Hello, I tried the suggested steps on Firefox 101.0.1 (64-bit) on windows 11 Pro, but unfortunately it does seems to work :( Address bar search shortcuts for bookmarks, history and tabs are working BUT for tags it is **NOT working anymore as of June 2022**. Supporting question in forum https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1380906#answer-1514902

Comment: @avimehenwal It seems to work again. What I would like to do is shift-click multiple tags to list all (boolean AND) bookmarks that have all these tags or list all (boolean OR) bookmarks that have at least one of these tags. Is that possible?

Comment: @cipricus Where is that answer?

Comment: @d-b - I have edited and un-deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Also, `*` can be typed before or after the search terms.

So, in order to search  `Tags: work,book`, type:

`*work book`

or

`work book*`

---

If typing `*` is too difficult, an addon that works at the date of this post provides a button that triggers a field where the key words can be typed: [Search Bookmarks Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-bookmarks-button/).

---

Some application launchers can search among internet bookmarks. In Linux there are many solutions, I hope there are in other systems too.

[Gnome](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/149/search-firefox-bookmarks-provider/) and [Plasma](https://web.archive.org/web/20190523034028/https://forum.antergos.com/topic/3133/how-to-recognize-firefox-bookmarks-in-krunner) desktops have search tools with that capability already.

---

When lacking that feature in Linux, one could use Synapse as it is desktop-agnostic. Synapse has a plugin to search Chromium bookmarks, but not one for Firefox; having Chromium installed and importing Firefox bookmarks in Chromium does the trick.

So, enabling the plugin:

[image]

search your terms and press the right-arrow key to select the "Internet" category to the right:

[image]

Comment: What makes you think + for tag search has been replaced with * ? The recently updated https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/address-bar-autocomplete-firefox?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=awesome-bar-find-your-bookmarks-history-and-tabs#w_changing-results-on-the-fly still mentions + for that purpose, no?

Comment: @JohnDoe - edited.