# How to use multiple tags in firefox browser URL search

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I am using tags to manage my bookmarks in Firefox.
Scenario:
I have multiple URLs that have been tagged with more than one tag.
I want to list all URLs in the URL bar, which have only the mentioned tags. I think this can be accomplished by using the advanced search option.

Like so in the URL bar:

```
+ Tag1 Tag2
```

The idea is this should list all URLs in my bookmarks which have both of these tags.
However it does not seem to work and shows all bookmarked URLs that have either of these words even in the URL name or description.

I have attached a screenshot demonstrating the problem.
[image: screenshot demonstrating the problem]

Is there a way I can force search of all bookmarks that have both of these tags (out of many tags of an URL)?

```
System Information:
1> Windows 8 Pro, 64 bit.
2> Firefox 33.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to repeat the `+` operator like this: `+ java + tools + Tag3 + Tag4`.

Answer (score 0):

There may have been a time when the syntax you tried `+ tag1 tag2` did not work in Firefox. However, when I try this again in **Aug 2019 (Firefox 68.0.2)**, that syntax actually works.

On the other hand, the URL bar syntax `+ tag1 + tag2` as another answer here mentions no longer appears to work on my version of Firefox.

Another user shares a similar answer to this here: https://superuser.com/a/771139/61629